# What is a modern alternative to Thinkpad Buttons?

Tags: ubuntu, thinkpad, hotkeys, osd

A lot of people say that Thinkpad Buttons prevents the CPU from saving power and shouldn't be used but it is the only solution for Thinkpads I know that shows OSD for volume keys. `hotkey-setup` that came with Ubuntu Jaunty can't even intercept those keys. Is there a better alternative, that is good enough with CPU sleeping states and can show OSD?

Comment: What do you mean with tpb? What is it short for?

Comment: It's short for "ThinkPad Buttons". It's one of the tools under Linux that can make Thinkpad special buttons work. The only one if you need OSD though.

Comment: ok, never heard of it.

Comment: When you say OSD, do mean getting visual feedback when you volume up / down?  I have jaunty installed on a t40 and a t61p and I get this behavior by default.

Comment: Hm, I don't, there's no OSD at all.

Comment: Also - use xev to watch any key & button presses and mouse events. It should already be installed on your machine.

Answer (score 2):

The modern equivalent is the [HAL daemon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HAL_%28software%29), `hald`.  When hald is running you can:

1. [Get](http://linux.die.net/man/1/hal-get-property) or [Set](http://linux.die.net/man/1/hal-set-property) properites
2. Find device objects by [property matching](http://linux.die.net/man/1/hal-find-by-property) or by [capability matching](http://linux.die.net/man/1/hal-find-by-capability)
3. [List](http://linux.die.net/man/1/lshal) all the hal devices

Try:

```
lshal | grep input
```

or

```
hal-find-by-capability --capability input | xargs -n1 lshal -u
```

for a list of all the input devices & buttons known to hald

**Update**
I'm using Gnome.  If you're running KDE, you can try kcontrol. Refer to [this HowTo](http://floatingsun.net/articles/ubuntu-t42/) - it's a bit dated.  kcontrol is kde3, systemsettings in kde4.  I think the nvram group setting are still applicable.

Comment: sure but there's no OSD :)

Comment: I'm currently running Ubuntu 9.04 on a T61p, my volume keys work and there is associated partially translucent OSD when adjusting the volume.  Maybe I don't get you're question really.  I haven't installed anything special to make this happen.

Comment: My OSD looks like this: http://sites.google.com/site/daveparillo/downloads/superuser/volume-osd.png?attredirects=0

Comment: @DaveParillo, hm, no, I don't have any visual confirmation when I use volume button or any other special kind of button for that matter. I hope that upgrade to 9.10 will cure the problem then.

Comment: Note that hald is no deprecated, and (mostly) replaced by `udev`.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a ThinkPad to try these on, but googling for "thinkpad buttons linux" gave me these two promising links:
1. http://www.thinkwiki.org/wiki/How_to_get_special_keys_to_work
2. http://www.thinkwiki.org/wiki/ThinkPad_Button